# How to set different colors for multiply selected dates?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I use `com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView` in my app.
Is it possible to set different colors for multiply selected dates? Or I need use custom calendarView? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set different decorators for each day of the week. Each decorator will have a different selector associated to it.

For example:

```
mcv.addDecorators(
            new MondayDecorator(this),
            new TuesdayDecorator(),
            ...
    );
```

```
public class MondayDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

    private final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    private final Drawable drawable;

    public MySelectorDecorator(Activity context) {
        drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.monday_selector);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        day.copyTo(calendar);
        int weekDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        return weekDay == Calendar.MONDAY;
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.setSelectionDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

and finally your monday_selector:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_monday_selector" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_monday_selector" />

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

I haven't tried it but this should work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But what if I have 5 selected dates and I want for every selected date set different color? and then if I make one of the dates not selected change it's color?

Comment: Please review the following link and see if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914857/how-to-set-color-in-selected-date-of-material-calendar-view

Comment: I think your first answer is right. I think problem is that I wrong get selected dates